# How can I click on the first Select2 element from Selenium with Scala and BootStrap

Tags: java, jquery, scala, selenium, jquery-select2

I'm testing with ScalaTest, FlatSpec and Selenium, an Scala application with Bootstrap3 and JQuery, and I'm getting a strange behavior with the Select2 elements.

When I want to click on a Select2 element, I try these options:

```
click on xpath("... My XPath ...")
```

or

```
click on cssSelector(" ... My cssSelector ...")
```

or

```
blahblah.webElement.click()
```

All of these possibilities works fine, but I've found an exception.

This is my Select elements definition with BootStrap 3:

```
// mySelect1
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect1"), ("" -> "All") +: mySelect1.values.map(r => r.code -> Messages("mySelect1." + r.code)), '_label -> Messages("mySelect1"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )

// mySelect2
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect2"), options = Seq(""->"All", "true"->"Yes", "false"->"No"), '_label -> Messages("mySelect2"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )

// mySelect3
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect3"), options = Seq(""->"All", "true"->"Yes", "false"->"No"), '_label -> Messages("mySelect3"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )
```

When I want to click on the first Select2 (mySelect1) I got the classic error:

> InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be
>   used for actions

But when I click on the others two (mySelect2 and mySelect3) elements works fine. Only the first one throws the error.

If I change the definition order, the behavior is reproduced again on the first one. Not the others.

```
// mySelect2
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect2"), options = Seq(""->"All", "true"->"Yes", "false"->"No"), '_label -> Messages("mySelect2"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )

// mySelect3
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect3"), options = Seq(""->"All", "true"->"Yes", "false"->"No"), '_label -> Messages("mySelect3"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )

// mySelect1
@b3.select( filterForm("mySelect1"), ("" -> "All") +: mySelect1.values.map(r => r.code -> Messages("mySelect1." + r.code)), '_label -> Messages("mySelect1"), '_class -> "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" )
```

And finally, if a click only on the second one and on the third one, forgetting the first one, I've not got any error and it works fine.

Is this a bug? Anyone has found with some like this? It happens with Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Post the exact selenium code that you are using and also the rendered HTML.